# Trouble with ViewPager displaying Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to get a fragment with three tabs displayed using ViewPager. Initially I used to instantiate the fragment from the Activity using FragmentMgr, this worked fine. When I converted this navigation using ViewPager, this Fragment is no longer displayed.

MainActivity.java

When I initiate Fragment like this, it gets displayed. eg:

```
LaunchListFragment fragment = new LaunchListFragment();
fragment.newInstance(LIST_TYPE);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container,   
 fragment).commit();
```

I tried this change above code to make use of ViewPager as follows:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new LaunchPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),LIST_TYPE));
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

where LaunchPageAdapter calls LaunchListFragment.

LaunchPageAdapter.java

```
public class LaunchPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private static String select="";

    public LaunchPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String type) {
        super(fm);
        select=type;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return LaunchListFragment.newInstance(select);
            case 1:
                return AddTeamFragment.newInstance();
           
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }
```

Here is LaunchListFragment.java

```
public class LaunchListFragment extends ListFragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public static  String LIST_TYPE = "invalid";
GenericListData g_data[] = null;
 
   
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_launch_list,
                container, false);
        
         setActionTabs();
         setList();
        return (result);
    }

   
   public static Fragment newInstance(String type) {
    Fragment frag = new LaunchListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    LIST_TYPE=type;
    args.putString(LIST_TYPE, type);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return (frag);
}
```

This is main.xml layout used by MainActivity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools=  "match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:name="com.teammanager.ItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_launch_list.xml used by LaunchListFragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

When I debug this, I can see LaunchListFragment is getting instantiated, onCreate and onCreate View is called, it just won't get displayed. :(

Can anyone here let me know if I am missing anything here in my ViewPager implementation?

**Update**

When I called LaunchListFragment without using Viewpager, I set the content view first and passed R.id.item_detail_container which is the id of the FrameLayout where I want the fragment to be displayed. Please refer to main.xml earlier

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main.xml);
 LaunchListFragment fragment = new LaunchListFragment();
 fragment.newInstance(LIST_TYPE);
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container,    
  fragment).commit();
```

When I changed this to use ViewPager, I am not sure where I'm directing the Fragment to be displayed. In my fragment onView I'm inflating fragment_launch_list and returning the View. But how will the view pager know where to set the fragment view. Is it inside the id pager?

I'm an absolute beginner, I apologize if all these are naive questions.

Cheers.

Comment: Just curious, why is it `select` variable `static`?

Comment: I used to set the value select from other fragments earlier, it is a lazy way of passing data between objects.

Comment: when you want to transfer values from one fragment to another then use interface's. Not use static variable, it's not correct way..!

Answer (score 2):

The question description is perfectly suitable to the problem I just had. I know the question is old but may this help other who face same. @Geoplex have not shown code of `LaunchPageAdapter` class. So I'm not sure if this solves his problem or not. But for me that worked.

In my PagerAdapter, the
`public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)` was overridden. I removed that method and allowed superClass to handle it. That started giving my expected result.

Answer (score 1):

This is useful for you,

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments=null;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager=null;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragments=fragments;
        this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().commitAllowingStateLoss();
        return fragments.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container,0,fragments.get(0));
    }
    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged()
    {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        fragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(fragments.get(position));
    }
    public void replaceItem(int position,Fragment fragment)
    {
        fragments.set(position, fragment);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnPageChangeListener,TabListener
{
    private android.support.v4.view.ViewPager mViewPager=null;
    private ViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter=null;
    private ActionBar action=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        initilizeViewPager();
        action=getActionBar();
                action.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
                action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                action.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }
         public void initilizeViewPager()
     {
                 mViewPager=(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
         List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
                fragments.add(LaunchListFragment.newInstance(select));
                fragments.add(AddTeamFragment.newInstance());
                fragments.add(thirdFragment.newInstance());
                viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter();
mViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments));
                new setAdapterTask().execute();
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
     }
     private class setAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
     {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            Tab first=action.newTab().setTag("first").setText("First").setTabListener(MainActivity.this);
            Tab second=action.newTab().setTag("second").setText("Second").setTabListener(MainActivity.this);
Tab third=action.newTab().setTag("third").setText("Third").setTabListener(MainActivity.this);
            action.addTab(first);
            action.addTab(second);
                    action.addTab(third);
            }
        }
     }
     public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
     {}
     public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
     {}
     public void onPageSelected(int position) 
     {
         getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
     }
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
     public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
     }
     public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewpager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I copied your code and followed the instructions, the LaunchListFragment is not getting displayed. I debugged, it adds tabs on actionbar - that part works, then populate the list with correct values  etc, onView of Fragment is called, just that no list is displayed. Do you think this has anything to do with visibility settings for ViewPager?

Comment: Setting up of All fragments transactions should be populates on their parent(like activity or their parent fragment). I think your transactions on their activity, so you handle all view pager transactions and adding tabs inside of Activity.

Comment: Hi, Just now, I removed the setting ActionTab values from the LaunchListFragment to the MainActivity (parent activity). This did not make any changes, as in the LaunchListFragment is still not displaying using ViewPager. I suspect it is the layout, please do check my update in the initial question.

Comment: What is the problem you think is with main layout? and where I do I add the Activity? Is it missing </LinearLayout>, it is there, this comment is not showing it.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try that. Their, all transactions beyonds MainActivity..

Comment: Hi there, I changed my code to your updated code, still the Listview in LaunchListFragment is not displayed when I use ViewPager :( When I changed the main.xml layout to use Relative instead of LinearLayout, the itemListFragment in that was not getting displayed. I was using the layouts generated by eclipse when you choose Master/Detail Activity for your project. So I have a ListFragment on the leftside (Items List), then a FrameLayout and that's where I was trying to display a fragment with three tabs. Not sure to ditch all these and start over with simple activity/viewPager.