# android open specific tab fragment from click event in activity2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

I am new Android and currently working on a project involving navigation between the activities within the tabbed activity(**HomeActivity**). I am stuck at a point where I have to navigate to a specific tab fragment, say **Tab 2**, from a button click event from **Activity2**. I have been stuck at this issue for a while now any help would be appreciated.

I have a **recyclerview** on **tab2** which should be loaded when the tab2 opens after the click event is performed from **activity2**.

I have researched about it for a while but was not able to come to a solution after trying various of them. I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701042/starting-second-tab-fragment-of-first-activity-from-second-activity"). My code fragment is also similar to the one in the link but that is an unanswered question.

I have also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657438/nested-fragments-and-viewpager-issues-on-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078278/trouble-with-viewpager-displaying-fragments).

I would appreciate if I can get some help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

i have check your code your `activity1` is `HomePageActivity` and `activity2` is `CreateEvents`.

what your doing is: start `activity2` from `FloatingActionButton` button click

in activity2 onClick of `buttonCreateEvent` you are again start `activity1`.

***instead of start activity again just finish activity2 your problem solve if your activity start from TAB2 then when activity1 show again its show TAB2 default(at this point i assume you know life cycle methods of activity) when activity1 show again in restart method update your data using flag or static variable***

---

### please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked exactly as you told. But, now a discrepancy has occurred. The information that has to be displayed on tab 2 is being displayed on both tab1 and tab2 and once we swipe among the tabs, the default content of tab3 is being displayed again and again on tab1 instead of its tab1's content. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open [this link](http://www.androidbie.com/2017/01/android-sliding-tab-how-to-open.html)

On link attached, i used `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);` value `1` got from tab that opened.

To send the value `1` to my `Activity`, i uses `sharedPreference`

=======

Everytime i open the Tab, `sharedPreferences` always save the tab's value.

Value :

`0` for **Tab 1**

`1` for **Tab 2**

`2` for **Tab 3**

Hope the solution on the link attached helps you.